# Make a div display above all divs (Absolute positioning)

Tags: html, css

When i click share button, div with social media icons (class="soc-icons") is displayed behind a div positioned below (class = "bioDivContainer").

[image]

HTML code

```
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 quoteDiv col-xs-12">
        <p id="quotes"></p>
        <!--end of "quotes" p-->
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getQuote" type="button">Get Quote</button>
        <div class="like&share pull-right">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart social-but" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Like the Quote"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share the Quote">
      <div class="soc-icons">
        <span><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>    
</span>
          <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter"
                        data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title=
                        "Tweet the Quote"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" div-->
```

CSS Code

```
.soc-icons {
  margin-top:20px;
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
  z-index:10;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  display:none;
  background-color:white;
}

.soc-icons span {
  display:inlnie;
}
```

What can i do to display div with **soc-icons** class above a div below.

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Comment: kind of confuse. `soc-icons` is already above other element

Comment: Nope, on the picture it is seen that div below with short bio overlap social media icons div. So i need to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the    `.quoteDiv  {z-index: 1}`

Comment: Great help! I did not help about putting z-index: 1 inside .quoteDiv. I thought z-index is applied only to absolute positioned divs.